# Is it a waste to create a class with only 1 object in c++

Tags: c++, class, logic

If you wanted to store information about 1 thing (such as a user), would it be a waste to create a class?

This class would only ever hold 1 object, which would be the user. For me it seems clean and easy to understand if using a class but I don't know if it's wasteful or not.

```
class c_User{
public:
    int GetAge();
    string GetName();

    void SetAge();
    void SetName();
private:
    int m_userAge;
    string m_userName;
}
```

These can be neatly accessed in main. Once they're set. It can also have it's own functions and has a lot of control.

```
int main(){
    c_User User;
    //Set

    //Get
    User.GetAge();
    User.GetName();
}
```

Below is a way to achieve the same thing without using a class. Once they're set.

```
int main(){
    int userAge;
    string userName;
    //Set

    //Get
    userAge;
    userName;
}
```

They aren't actually being used for anything above. But the idea of accessing them, and then using them in some way.

I'm not sure if the method without the class would get confusing once it holds more information. Everything I've done has been small-scale but I'm trying to move onto larger projects with more information.

Is it a waste to create a class that only has 1 object?

Comment: Define "waste" / "wasteful".

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: If more than one program is going to use it then it might not be a waste. When planing any project you have to weigh the benefits verses the cost of design implementation. There is no point in over engineering your application, If I was writing a simple text processing tool that dealt with customer information would I creat a full featured Customer class to represent them? Doubtful. Why wast 20 minutes on a 10 minute job?

Comment: I'd generally go ahead and define the class. You may well want more instances later, so avoid the Singleton (anti-)pattern unless the type's correctness truly depends on there only ever being one instance (at least at one time).

Comment: A class is a type. you introduce a new type when it helps your code.

Comment: I think the idea of having a class for this particular simple case of one user is better than just using variables inside the main, who knows you might have multiple users in future and also what to read/write credentials of users from/to file. In all these case a class would be pretty darn good way by simply overloading of >> and << streamings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It allows you to treat both values as a single entity, which is always good - conceptually, a single entity is what you have. Since your class is a simple container for two values with both getters and setters, it doesn't achieve any encapsulation and could be more simply written as:

```
struct User 
{
    int Age;
    string Name;
};
```

And now the syntactic cost of defining that seems more in line with its actual usefulness.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it is generally good practice, when writing in C++ to stick to using classes.  In this particular instance, you could certainly use a struct.  But as you grow with the language the more you know about the class paradigm, the better.

Writing "c-style" code in a C++ works, but can actually lead to optimization issues in large-scale programs down the road.